# Get current number of columns in alternating rows

Tags: php, math, optimization

I need to write a PHP function, but in fact I have a math question.

I have a variable number of results.
I want to print my results in alternating rows of 3 and 4 columns.
To do so, I have to know for each result, in what type of row it is located (aka, how many columns it's row has).

[An example of a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4ftq.png)

Ik know I can do it in PHP using 2 variables, but I assume there if a mathematical function to calculate for each item (which has an index starting at 0) in what type of row it is situated.

Comment: Since he provides an example, the question is comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to determine on which kind of a row you are at.

```
$className = (($index % 7) < 3 ? 'row-with-three' : 'row-with-four')
```

Since the pattern repeats every 7 objects we start by wrapping the value around, `$index % 7`. This will provide a value between `0` and `6` inclusively. Then we can check if it's one of the first three by doing `< 3`, if it is then it's a row that has three objects. Otherwise it has four objects.

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I needed.
This reduced my code by 13 lines.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

use count() to figure it out for you.

```
<?php
    for( $i=0; $r=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ); $i++ ){
         if( count( $r ) == 4 ){
             echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
         }
         if( count( $r) == 3 ){
             echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td colspan=\"2\"></td></tr>";
         }
     }
?>
```